# spring boot war to external tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy my Spring boot project on external Tomcat server. I followed  all given advices here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging, however i am a bit confused as i deployed it on the server and everything is ok, but i am getting 404 error every time i access any of pages. Also, i add to **application.properties**

```
server.context-path=/bqp
```

so i use url's like this http://128.0.169.5:8082/bqp/

[image]

**UPDATED:**

my spring-config.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bionic" />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="com.bionic.quizzes" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizzes" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

**Also, I could easy deploy it by main method of Spring boot. But I should deploy it on remote server.**

**Application.class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please post your servlet.xml?

Comment: @VictorViola, the only xml i use is spring-config.xml. Should i post it?

Comment: Yes, please. You need to define a view resolver.

Comment: Do you have a `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass in your application?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, yes, i have

Comment: `server.context-path` only configures the context path when you're using an embedded servlet container. It has no effect when you deploy the application to an external server.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, ok, but why it still does not work?

Answer (score -1):

Try put this code on your servlet.xml

```
     <bean class= 
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/bqp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> //if you are using .jsp
    </bean>
```

Comment: If you are really using the configurations via xml, try the code above.

Comment: Spring boot apps don't need view resolver. Also prefix should be `/WEB-INF/...`